# How is "Application UI" within the scope of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just noticed Code Review's FAQ includes "Application UI" in the "If your question is about..." section. What exactly is meant by that?

[User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) is the site for UI/UX issues, though UX.SE is not a review site. How does Application UI fit in with the two site's scopes? Is Code Review for the *code* side of the UI? If that's the case I wouldn't consider that "Application UI" it's just UI code.

In addition, this site is about "sharing code"--I don't see how pure UI issues could possibly fall into that scope. If the issue is "how do I make this code work to create this UI" that's an SO question; UI code is never language agnostic.

I haven't seen any questioned migrated from Code review to UX.SE so I don't think people are confused as to which site is for what, but I don't think this site's FAQ is very clear on what is meant by Application UI being in-scope.

Comment: While I agree with your post, the point `UI code is never language agnostic` does not imply that it would only be suitable for SO. After all, if I think I am violating *separation of concerns* with my UI code, I *should* post it on codereview, not on SO, where it would be **closed**.

Comment: I meant that "how do I meant this UI code work" pretty much has to be a question for programmers in a specific language to solve in a practical sense--thus SO. It's practice, not theory. If the issue is separation of concerns then that should be the wording, not Application UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph is:

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review. If you are looking for specific feedback about…
>
> - Code correctness
> - Best practices and design pattern usage in your code
> - Application UI
> - Security issues in a code snippet, etc.
> - The performance of your code

Whatever is meant by "Application UI", I think it's evident that it's the odd one in the list, the only sentence that doesn't somehow includes the word "code". To me it's just poor wording, and I can't really think of an alternative phrase that would still be reasonably within the "Application UI" domain.

It confuses more than helps, let's just get rid of it.

---

**update**: "Application UI" is no longer in the faq. (thanks @sepp2k)

Comment: Do we have any example questions specifically about UI code or "Application UI"? It was explicitly included and I'm having a difficult time imagining why.

Comment: I searched for "application UI" too and found nothing as well; just people quoting the full FAQ section.

Comment: I agree. Consider it gotten rid of.